# Issue setting framenumber in videocapture from bunch of images

Tags: c++, opencv

In short I've implemented a videotracking and label system in qt4.8 and opencv3 using c++.
I can load videofiles like .mpeg and folders containing images(.jpg) into `cv::VideoCapture`, tracking and labeling works fine as well. The GUI contains a trackbar updating to the current frame in relation to total frames. I can grab the current position on the trackbar and drag it to set a new current frame (forward/backward) to quickly jump inside the video.

Problem: everything works fine for video files, but I am not able jump using the trackbar when I load a bunch of images from a folder to create a video:
the trackbar jumps to 0(start), because the current frame is accidentally set to -9.22337e+18.

```
// callback when trackbar is moved
void MainWindow::on_frameSlider_sliderMoved(int position)
{
    // get current frame, render it and update UI elements
    if(position < videoPlayer->getNumberOfFrames())
    {
        std::cerr << "frameposition before " << videoPlayer->getCurrentFrame() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "frameposition bar " << position << std::endl;
        videoPlayer->setCurrentFrame(position);
        std::cerr << "frameposition after " << videoPlayer->getCurrentFrame() << std::endl;

        ui->currentTimeLabel->setText( helper::getFormattedTime( position/(int)videoPlayer->getFrameRate()) );
        ui->currentFrameLabel->setText( QString::number(position) );
        //stuff to render frames (it's already broken here, but displays the processed framenumber)
        videoPlayer->play();
        helper::stopPlayer(this);
    }
}

void Player::setCurrentFrame( int frameNumber ){
    capture->set(cv::CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameNumber);
}
```

The output is as follows:

frameposition before 7

frameposition bar 10

frameposition after -9.22337e+18

processed: -9.22337e+18

frameposition before -9.22337e+18

frameposition bar 0

frameposition after 0

processed: -9.22337e+18

frameposition before 0

frameposition bar 23

frameposition after -9.22337e+18

Is this a common problem when setting frames in captures from a bunch of images? How can I solve it?

best wishes

Comment: This looks like an int overflow problem.

Comment: Do you have an idea how it comes? Like I said, it works fine for videos, where I got similar values from the trackbar (set frame# between 1 and total number of frames ~3k).
Another thread has the same problem, but there is now accepted answer/solution. He thinks that it a problem inside the opencv videostream loaded from an image sequence. Maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: check source of videoPlayer, maybe it expects an unsigned ?

Comment: It expects double, but even with casting the error occurs.